# Trouble importing multiple modules in Pythonanywhere fiels

Tags: python, numpy, pythonanywhere

Trying to run this code on pythonanywhere to send out automatic reminders in the morning to people with upcoming interviews. It works the first time I run the pythonanywhere.py file but breaks every subsequent time. This error does not happen on .ipynb files.

```
#Import pandas for dataframes
#Import datetime to check day 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
import requests 
from twilio.rest import Client

#datetime_object = datetime.datetime.now() #Get current time
today = datetime.date.today() #Get current day 
today = pd.Timestamp(today) #Convert current day into usable formate
interviewees = pd.ExcelFile('/home/drblessing/InterviewCandidates.xlsx') #Load in list of interview candidates
interviews_df = interviewees.parse() #Parse interview candidates into dataframe
Reminders = (interviews_df['Date'] - datetime.timedelta(days=1)) #Take their interview day and subtract one to send out reminder
Reminders_df = interviews_df[Reminders == today] #Checking which candidates have reminders today 
Reminder_phones = pd.Series.tolist(Reminders_df['Phone'])
Reminder_emails = pd.Series.tolist(Reminders_df['Email'])
account_sid = '****************************'
auth_token = '5**************************'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

for i in Reminder_phones:
    message = client.messages.create(
                              body='Hi there! This is an automated message to remind you about your interview on 2/20 at 1:00 pm. ',
                              from_='**********',
                              to=['******************']
                          )
    print(message.sid)

def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/dbless.net/messages",
        auth=("api", "*********************************"),
        data={"from": "urmom <mailgun@dbless.net>",
            "to": Reminder_emails,
            "subject": "Test",
            "text": "I had to show python who's BOSS "})

send_simple_message()
```

However, after the first run I get this error:

**RuntimeError: implement_array_function method already has a docstring**

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It appears that this is [a problem with numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14384). There is suggestion that downgrading numpy to version `1.15.4` might help.

As an aside, I know that pandas tutorials normally import numpy, but they tend to go on and use it later in the script. In this case you don't seem to be using numpy anywhere, so could you remove that import and see if your script still works?

Comment: I also love Twilio. Okay, thanks for the help! I tried removing NumPy and it still doesn't work. I think it has to do with the scripts on pythonanywhere. They run the first time then break the second time, so I have to restart the whole script and then run it again fresh. Not sure why that happens though?

Comment: There's a [thread about this on the pythonanywhere forum too](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/21225/). Also suggestions are to downgrade numpy and it may work. Have you tried that?